# I want to prove that $m||v||_1\le ||v||$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(V,||\cdot ||)$ a finite-dimensional real normed space, and $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ a basis. We define $||v||_1=\sqrt{x_1^2+...+x_n^2}$, where $x_1,...,x_n$ are the coordinates of $v$.

I already proved that there exists $w\in S:=\{v\in V:||v||_1=1\}$ such that $$||w||\le ||v||$$ for every $v\in S$.

Now I want to prove that $$m||v||_1\le ||v||$$ for every $v\in V.$, but I can't see why we have that.

Any hint? Thanks.

Edit: I forgot... $m:=||w||$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: First note, that $w \ne 0$, let $m := \|w\| >0$. Now let $v \in V$. Then $v':= v/\|v\|_1 \in S$,  hence $m = \|w\| \le \|v'\|$. Now use the defition of $v'$ and homogenity of $\|\cdot \|$.